# Exporting ReportViewer to HTML

Tags: webforms, export, reportviewer

Does anyone know a way of providing an Export to HTML for ReportViewer WebForms?

I know by default, Image, PDF and Excel are supported formats. I'm guessing there must be some sort of workaround to get the HTML of the report out?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this link](http://pareshjagatia.wordpress.com/2008/05/03/export-reportviewer-report-to-pdf-excel/).

You use the Render method and specify the format for export.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the 2010 ReportViewer control then it appears HTML4.0 it has been removed from this version (It did work fine in the 2008 version) if you are executing in local mode.

See http://www.gotreportviewer.com/

**Question: What are the limitations of ReportViewer control?**

> A: Unlike the Report Server the
>   ReportViewer control does not connect
>   to databases or execute queries. Also,
>   in local mode **the only export
>   formats available are Excel, Word and
>   PDF**. (In remote mode all formats
>   supported by the Report Server are
>   available.) The ReportViewer control
>   cannot be extended by adding custom
>   renderers or custom report items.
>
> Besides additional export formats, the
>   Report Server offers better
>   scalability, central storage,
>   management and access control of
>   reports, caching, subscriptions, etc.